# mysql on openshift: Failed to execute: 'control restart'

Tags: mysql, openshift

I can't restart my application. Getting message: 
Unable to complete the requested operation. 
could not open session 
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/53fa3c33e0b8cdaa4c000b36/mysql

What can be done in such a case?

Comment: Can you try again and see if you are still having this issue?