# nodejs/postgresql on openshift: Failed to execute: 'control restart'

Tags: node.js, postgresql, openshift

Similar to another question.

[mysql on openshift: Failed to execute: 'control restart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504229/mysql-on-openshift-failed-to-execute-control-restart)

could not open session
could not open session

Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/.../postgresql
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/.../nodejs

Has anyone encountered anything similar? Our app was working yesterday and not today anymore

Comment: Do you not get any logs? Is there a verbose/debug flag you can set when trying to do this?

Comment: Looks like OpenShift was having an issue, can you try this again and see if it works now/

Comment: @developercorey, Hi! thanks for the update! We're good to go now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved by Openshift already :) @developercorey